# Limit action to only once per iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, security, ios8

I am building an iOS 8 app for iPhone where free credit is given to every user that downloads and runs the app. To prevent abuse, I want to give free credit only once per phone.

Is there a foolproof way of determining if my app has already been installed and/or run on a specific phone? (You may assume that the phone is not jail-broken.)

Comment: Why a phone? Wouldn't it be smarter to limit it per user account? What if a phone changes hands and the next user can't get the free credit?

Comment: @Pekka웃: Because creating a user account is free. Buying a phone is not. Fair point, though.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's probably going to be rare for someone to switch accounts (and lose all their purchased apps, settings, and media) just to score some more free credits - unless they're worth actual money, of course.... but then you should probably be linking the credit to a credit card or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, first off you are wanting to identify a phone. But what is the user sells it phone, then the new owner does not get the free credits.

Apple made it impossible to identify a device by any unique identifier.
You best option is to store a flag in the keychain, because it will persist even if the user deletes your app.

Comment: What I want is slightly weaker than a unique identifier. As I understand, if the app is uninstalled, keychain data gets wiped when the user updates iOS to the next major version.

Comment: The keychain should only be wiped if the devices gets a full reset, not on a OS update. They only identifier that Apple allows you to get is the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html). But this one will be reset when every all the app of one vendor are removed.

Comment: From experience, keychain data gets wiped with an update from iOS 7 to iOS 8, if the corresponding app is uninstalled.

Comment: I guess you are out of luck then.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. but you can used web service so it possible.
when used download app that time device token and device udid or get current ios detail than all detail send to server than you can see all detail in you server so you can approve than determining.

but here one problem apply store approve or not i don't know.
you will check than implement.

Comment: This will not work, since as a develop you can not acces the UDID or any other unique identifier of an app.

Answer (score -1):

Once per device doesn't serve the purpose. You can always check for a first run by setting a flag in the user defaults, and change it once the user runs the application for the first time. An alternative to this would be, having a method of authentication, by which you can verify the user and check if he has already availed his free credit.

Comment: I don't have authentication. As for setting a flag in the user defaults, aren't those resettable by the user?

Comment: Yes, but there requires some effort. Considering your application, it's best to store it in the Keychain or have some sort of authentication by which you can identify the user.